# How to use whole word regex search for Devanagari text?

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, hindi, xregexp

My HTML code with Devanagari words

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TODO</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    मंत्री मुख्यमंत्री 
</body>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="xregexp_20.js"></script>
    <script src="addons/unicode/unicode-base.js"></script>
    <script src="addons/unicode/unicode-scripts.js"></script>
    <script src="my.js"></script>
</html>
```

My javascript code

```
var html = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];
var fullpage_content = html.innerHTML;

var regex = RegExp("मंत्री", "g");
var count = fullpage_content.match(regex);
console.log("count in page : " + count+ ", " + count.length);

//use of word boundry ,not supported by devanagari characters
regex = RegExp("\\bमंत्री\\b", "g");
count = fullpage_content.match(regex);
console.log("count in page : " + count);

regex = XRegExp("मंत्री");
var match = XRegExp.matchChain(fullpage_content, [regex]);
console.log("count in page : " + match + ", " + match.length);

//xregex do not support word boundry \\b
regex = XRegExp("\\bमंत्री\\b");
match = XRegExp.matchChain(fullpage_content, [regex]);
console.log("count in page : " + match + ", " + match.length);
```

Output of js (on Chrome)

> count in page : मंत्री,मंत्री, 2
>
> count in page : null
>
> count in page : मंत्री,मंत्री, 2
>
> count in page : , 0

Whole word search should give one as answer, but regexp and XRegExp both are failing me. I need some help.

Comment: Can you give us the fiddle for this ?

Comment: @PrabhatJain I created one for me. You can have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/es63p/

Comment: can you please check your fiddle, if something is helping.

Comment: here is the updated fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/es63p/3/ BTW I think the person who has asked this questions wants to use xregexp library. The script is not returning the actual word count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
regex = XRegExp("(?:^|[^\\p{Devanagari}\\p{L}])मंत्री(?=[^\\p{Devanagari}\\p{L}]|$)");
```

solved it. Thanks to Louis in particular.
I tested a more rigorous test case before finalizing.

मंत्री मंत्रीमंत्री मंत्रीमं ममंत्री मंत्री मंत्री  मंत्री. .मंत्री मंत्री- <मंत्री मंत्री> मंत्री, ,मंत्री ,मंत्री, मंत्री,मंत्री, ,मंत्री,मंत्री,

मंत्री, मंत्री

मंत्री,मंत्री मंत्री मुख्यमंत्री

Answer (score 3):

Using this regexp I can get a match on मंत्री but exclude मुख्यमंत्री:

```
var regex = XRegExp("(?:^|\\P{L})मंत्री(?=\\P{L}|$)");
```

What this does is match मंत्री if it:

1. Is at the beginning of the string or preceded by a character which Unicode considers a non-Letter, and
2. Is at the end of the string or followed by a character which Unicode considers a non-Letter.

Note that this is slightly different from what `\b` does because `\b` does not match digits. For instance, `/\bmantri\b/` won't match `mantri123` because `1`, `2`, and `3` are considered to be part of words and thus do not mark a word boundary. If you want something that emulates `\b` then this would do it:

```
var regex = XRegExp("(?:^|[^\\p{L}\\p{N}])मंत्री(?=[^\\p{L}\\p{N}]|$)");
```

The difference with the first regexp is that with this one मंत्री cannot be preceded or followed by a digit.

I've used a negative lookahead at the end of the regular expression so the character that follows your word is excluded from the results. There is no equivalent negative lookbehind so if there is a character before मंत्री, it *will* appear in the results. You'll have to decide what you want to do with this character for your specific application.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in fiddle and check if something is helping you

```
alert(fullpage_content);
//match(/मंत्री/g);
alert("मंत्री मुख्यमंत्री".match(/मंत्री/g));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that each word is followed by one or more space as character breaks then following js regular expression will give you the correct result

```
console.log("count inline without xRegExp:" + "मंत्री मुख्यमंत्री".match(/मंत्री\s+/g));
```